# Replace some part of string from object with variable or function return

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, replace

I have object contain string on config.js

```
exports.message = {
    fromname    : 'admin@bebestorescake.com',
    fromemail   : 'admin@bebestorescake.com', 
    subject     : 'subjek {randomip} {email} {date}', 
    text        : 'Plaintext version of the message',
    letter      : 'your-letter.html',
    list        : 'your-list.txt'
}
```

In another file I need to replace {email} {date} {randomip} string to some variable or function return like this

```
{email} replace to email();
{date} replace to date();
{randomip} replace to randomip();
```

How to do that in Node.js

Comment: If the only thing you know is that `{randomip}` and `{email}` and `{date}` are somewhere in the `subject` you could use regexp to replace those strings with other strings.

Comment: What have you tried so far? There is an answer, but we won't do this for you. We are here to help you when you get stuck.

Comment: Damn, have I wrote too much? ;)

Comment: i have tried using replace-string module but it just replace one string. I cant do for multiple or many string

Comment: @MukhlisAkbarrudin using a global flag in regex might help you to replace all instances of a given string or regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just chain `String#replace()` for this:

```js
let exports = {};
exports.message = {
    fromname    : 'admin@bebestorescake.com',
    fromemail   : 'admin@bebestorescake.com', 
    subject     : 'subjek {randomip} {email} {date}', 
    text        : 'Plaintext version of the message',
    letter      : 'your-letter.html',
    list        : 'your-list.txt'
}

exports.message.subject = exports.message.subject
  .replace("{randomip}", randomip())
  .replace("{email}", email())
  .replace("{date}", date());

console.log(exports.message)

// replace this with your own logic
function email(){return "name@domain.tld"}
function randomip(){return "127.0.0.1"}
function date(){return (new Date()).toLocaleString()}
```

And if you are sure that you are not handling any user input, you can also use `eval`. It's really not evil, just misunderstood:

```js
let exports = {};
exports.message = {
  fromname: 'admin@bebestorescake.com',
  fromemail: 'admin@bebestorescake.com',
  subject: 'subjek {randomip} {email} {date}',
  text: 'Plaintext version of the message',
  letter: 'your-letter.html',
  list: 'your-list.txt'
}

exports.message.subject = exports.message.subject
  .replace(/{([a-zA-Z]+)}/g, function(match) {
    return eval(match.substring(1, match.length - 1) + "()");
  });

console.log(exports.message)

// replace this with your own logic
function email() {return "name@domain.tld"}
function randomip() {return "127.0.0.1"}
function date() {return (new Date()).toLocaleString()}
```

```js
let exports = {};
exports.message = {
  fromname: 'admin@bebestorescake.com',
  fromemail: 'admin@bebestorescake.com',
  subject: 'subjek {email} {email} {date}',
  text: 'Plaintext version of the message',
  letter: 'your-letter.html',
  list: 'your-list.txt'
}

exports.message.subject = exports.message.subject
  .replace(/{([a-zA-Z]+)}/g, function(match) {
    return eval(match.substring(1, match.length - 1) + "()");
  });

console.log(exports.message)

// replace this with your own logic
function email() {return "name@domain.tld"}
function randomip() {return "127.0.0.1"}
function date() {return (new Date()).toLocaleString()}
```

Comment: hey bro what if in the string there are two {e-mail} {e-mail} tags replace it will only change one not all

Comment: It shouldn't replace `e-mail` at all, because of the `-`

Comment: I just checked to confirm that `{email} {email}` *does* replace both, if you click the `Show code snippet` button, you can see that it does.

Answer (score 0):

You may use template literals as quick solution:

```
const replaceTemplate = () => {
  const {email, name} = require('./config.js')
  return `
    ${email} this is an email
    Hello ${name}
  `;
};
```

[Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) works great as well as well:

```
const template = 'This is an {email} for {name}';

const obj = {
  email: 'hello@world.com',
  name: 'John Doe'
};
Object.keys(obj).reduce((prev, curr) => prev.replace(`{${obj[curr]}}`), template)
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I would implement this would be to implement a replacer function, with a dispatch table:

```
let { message } = require('config');

function replaceTokens(template) {
  const dispatcher = {
    email: () => 'somestaticaddress@example.com',
    randomip: () => {
      const randomInt = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
      return `${randomInt()}.${randomInt()}.${randomInt()}.${randomInt()}`;
    },
    date: () => (new Date()).toISOString()
  };
  let output = template;
  template.match(/\{[^}]*\}/g)
    .map(match => match.substring(1, match.length - 1))
    .forEach(token => {
      output = output.replace(new RegExp(`{${token}}`,'g'), dispatcher[token]());
    });
  return output;
}

message.subject = replaceTokens(message.subject);
```

The above will replace *all* instances of the tokens in the subject.

Answer (score 0):

You may also replace the string in the config.js with function:

```
exports.message = {
    fromname    : 'admin@bebestorescake.com',
    fromemail   : 'admin@bebestorescake.com', 
    subject     : ({randomip, email, date}) => `subjekt ${randomip || ''} ${email || ''} ${date || ''}`, 
    text        : 'Plaintext version of the message',
    letter      : 'your-letter.html',
    list        : 'your-list.txt'
}
```

And then pass arguments when needed:

```
message.subject({
  email: email(), 
  date: date()
})
```